# Pagination isn't working

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, paging

I have a homepage view called FrontPage. Currently, it shows the pagination link like "1, 2, 3 Next->" as it should; when I click on *Next*, it goes to http://example.com, not http://example.com/page/1/0.

I have checked the taxonomy archive, and it is has the same problem. The same is true for the Blog posts.

I checked pager.inc, but I don't see any problem. I haven't hooked anything in template.php.

Why is the *Next* link pointing to the wrong page, and what could I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Including your versions of Drupal core and Views module might be helpful.

Any chance you're using the Global Redirect module? I had the same problem when I took a dev site live (Drupal 7.26, Views 7.x-3.7 and 7.x-3.7+22-dev, Global Redirect 7.x-1.5), and this patch in globalredirect.module addressed the issue.

https://drupal.org/node/1789546